# mgcb editor won't install with dotnet tool install -g dotnet-mgcb-editor

Tags: c#, monogame

when I type into the command prompt "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-mgcb-editor
mgcb-editor --register" It just changes the name of the window and stops doing anything is it installing?

Comment: I installed mgcb editor only yesterday. It works perfectly. Try installing with package manager console of Visual Studio.

Comment: Did it return? what os are your running?

Comment: I had some issues, and was able to work them out by using the command -v n 
(-v, --verbosity <LEVEL>   Set the MSBuild verbosity level. Allowed values are
q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic])
Perhaps you can try that, and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-mgcb-editor --verbosity n --version 3.8.0.1641 --tool-path (Your path [e.g. C:\dotnet_tools])
```

Then run

```
mgcb-editor --register
```

That way, you can see what's happening, and if the first command is successful (for more details, use --verbosity d). Because if the first fails, the second command might be stuck.

Installing in a custom location may be better, based on what I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools).